# Calling specialized template method from non-template class

Tags: c++, builder

I am unable to call method in specialized template class in non-template class.

I have a template class like below:

```
template<class T>
class Builder{

   Builder() { t = new T; }
   Builder &setName(const int &name);
   // other methods
   T &build();

protected:
    T *t;

}

template<class T>
T &Builder<T>::build() {
    return *t;
}

// other implementations
```

And I have a class inheriting from a specialized template class

```
class SomeClass;

//template<class T>
class SomeClassBuilder : public Builder<SomeClass> {

public:
    SomeClassBuilder() : Builder<SomeClass>() {}
    SomeClassBuilder &setAge(int age);
}
```

```
class SomeClass{
public:
    static SomeClassBuilder createExperiment(){
      return {};
    }
// other methods
}
```

However, when I try to use this SomeClassBuilder depending on how I chain the method calls I get errors sometimes. The code snippet below gives an error(`has no member named setAge`).

```
SomeClass::Engine()
            .setName("Name")
            .setAge(109)
            .build();
```

Chaining the method calls like below gives no error because the `setAge` method of the `SomeClass` class comes before those the template class.

```
SomeClass::Engine()
            .setAge(109)
            .setName("Name")
            .build();
```

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: You should add the definition of `SomeClass::Engine()`.

Comment: are you looking for a way to make it compile as desired or are you looking for an explanation why the error happens? slightly different answers they will have

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that the reference `SomeClassBuilder &` can be interpreted as `Builder<SomeClass> &` but not the other way round (for that you need dynamic cast). Since the methods of `Builder<T>` return a `Builder<T> &` this has indeed no `set_age` member. This is no problem with templating but with inheritance.

I see 3 solutions for this:

1. Always use `set_age` first, while the type the function is applied to is still `SomeClassBuilder &`.
2. Override all the functions in `SomeClassBuilder` such that they execute the method in the base class and then return `*this` as `SomeClassBuilder &`.
3. Use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), so add a template parameter `class Child` to the base class that gets the type of the Child that inherits and let all methods return `Child &` instead of `Builder &` and you have to `dynamic_cast` `this` before returning. Then `SomeClassBuilder` should inherit from `Builder<T, SomeClassBuilder>` (needs forward declaration).

Also: Don't use raw pointers for owning memory. A raw `new` in your code is not a good sign. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: Heh, you made just the same suggestion 10 seconds before I did =D

Comment: @LeontyevGeorgiy Yes, and now I also stole your link ;-P

Comment: @n314159 I used the first option but it isn't elegant enough in the sense that if another person ones to use my code I need to explicitly tell them how to chain the method calls.

What if I have multiple specialized template classes, using CRTP how till that work?

Comment: @user2987773 Yes, that is not that practical. Personally, I would use the second one since it is easiest for the user even if it is annoying to write all these functions (but note that it is no codeduplication since it calls the base methods and does not reimplement them). Maybe one could also get rid of writing these methods by some metaprogramming magic but I don't have an idea how right now.

Answer (score 1):

`Builder<SomeClass>::setName` returns `Builder<SomeClass>`, which surely doesn't have any `setAge()` methods. When you call `setAge()` first, you return `SomeClassBuilder` instead, and it does have this method, so, this behavior is just what is expected from compiler.

To work around that, you could try using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to return an actual `SomeClassBuilder`.

Basically, your builder definition would change to

```
template <typename T, typename Derived>
class Builder
{
//...
Derived& setName();
//...
};
```

and, for `SomeClassBuilder`:

```
class SomeClassBuilder: public Builder<T, SomeClassBuilder> { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the way you designed it, I think that there is no other choice than using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

To be more explicit, here is a working example that maybe will help you:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename OBJECT_TYPE, typename CRTP_BUILDER_IMPL>
class Builder
{
 public:
  Builder() : _p_object(std::make_unique<OBJECT_TYPE>()){};

  CRTP_BUILDER_IMPL& impl() { return static_cast<CRTP_BUILDER_IMPL&>(*this); }

  CRTP_BUILDER_IMPL& setName(const char* const& name)
  {
    // do the job using name ...

    return impl();
  };

 protected:
  std::unique_ptr<OBJECT_TYPE> _p_object;
};

template <typename OBJECT_TYPE>
class SomeClassBuilder : public Builder<OBJECT_TYPE, SomeClassBuilder<OBJECT_TYPE>>
{
  using base_type = Builder<OBJECT_TYPE, SomeClassBuilder<OBJECT_TYPE>>;

 public:
  SomeClassBuilder() : base_type() {}

  SomeClassBuilder& setAge(int age)
  {
    // do the job using age ...

    return *this;
  }

  std::unique_ptr<OBJECT_TYPE> build() { return std::move(base_type::_p_object); }
};

class SomeClass
{
  using builder_type = SomeClassBuilder<SomeClass>;

 public:
  static builder_type builder() { return builder_type(); }
};

int main()
{
  auto someClass = SomeClass::builder().setName("Name").setAge(109).build();

  auto someClass_2 = SomeClass::builder().setAge(109).setName("Name").build();
}
```